# Understanding and simulating a classic linear regression model with fixed coefficients

Tags: regression, self-study, simulation

I had used the GPT chat to ask some straightforward questions. However, one of the responses left me feeling quite confused. Currently, I am studying the classical regression model given by
$$y_t = x_t\beta + u_t,$$
where $t = 1,...,T$ and $x_t$ is a deterministic (fixed) variable. As a result, I requested GPT to generate two realizations of this model using Julia. Here is the provided answer:

```
# Realization 1
T = 100
x = fill(3, T)  # Fixed value of x for all observations (3 in this case)
y = 2 .* x .+ randn(T)  # Y values with a linear relationship to x
# Realization 2
T = 100
x = fill(3, T)  # Fixed value of x for all observations (3 in this case)
y = 2 .* x .+ randn(T)  # Y values with a linear relationship to x
```

So his response led me to wonder about the concept of a population model in the context of a classical linear regression model with fixed coefficients. This model is commonly used in introductory econometrics courses for pedagogical purposes, but in my case, it has been somewhat confusing.

In my understanding, the population model would be represented as:
$$y = x \beta + u $$
where $x$ is deterministic and fixed, while $y$ and $u$ are random variables. So, GPT's answer aligns with this definition. However, I had anticipated a slightly different response

```
T = 100
x = rand(T) # Fixed
# Realization 1
y = 2 .* x .+ randn(T)  # Y values with a linear relationship to x
# Realization 2
y = 2 .* x .+ randn(T)  # Y values with a linear relationship to x
```

And now I'm confused. Could you help me?

Comment: Purely as a general observation, there's no reason to expect ChatGPT to give a correct, useful or helpful answer to any query.

Comment: I don't have much of a problem with asking a question about gaps in an answer proposed by ChatGPT. However, the posted question might benefit from being edited to focus on the topic of interest, instead of referring to ChatGPT. That is, you might want to consider just asking your linear regression question without talking about ChatGPT.

Comment: This is actually a really deep question, André. Classical stats is steeped in the design of experiments tradition, where we pick $x$ variables in advance and don't consider them to be random. This would align with your idea of "a realization". However, in observational studies, the response given by ChatGPT, where the $x$ variables themselves are random, may be the more appropriate way to conceptualize things. This distinction has important practical implications: a classical confidence interval based on the t distribution is based on the "fixed X" assumption, whereas one based on...

Comment: ... bootstrapping will, since it resamples the $X$ variables, give an interval corresponding to the assumption that X has its own distribution, which needs to be marginalized out to secure a CI on the regression coefficients.

Comment: @John I would think bootstrapping the *residuals* in such circumstances would be the standard approach, thereby respecting the conditional aspect of the regression, regardless of the application.

Comment: @whuber yes interesting, I hadn't run into that before. A away to deal with CI's without assuming an error distribution but while conditioning fully on the X's. Very cool!